# NodeJS Not Exiting, How to find open handlers?

Tags: node.js, heroku, asynchronous, mongoose, q

I have a fairly simple NodeJS script that is not exiting gracefully when done (this is a worker and I want to fire it up using a cron job / heroku scheduler)

Once it has finished its task it just sits there waiting. It doesn't use express / a web server etc and as far as I can tell I have resolved all callbacks.

Is there some way to tell what node is still working on / what handlers are open?

My imported libraries are 
Request, Q & Mongoose.

Comment: Post your code and we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to close the mongodb connections that mongoose has open on your behalf by calling `mongoose.disconnect()`. Have you tried that?